# VBA not looping through any PowerPoint slides

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am simply trying to loop through PowerPoint slides using the following VBA code in Excel.

```
Sub test()

Dim slide As Object


For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides

    Debug.Print "test"

Next slide

End Sub
```

However I receive the message 'Runtime error '424'. Object required'. Anybody have any idea why ActivePresentation.Slides may not be functioning? I have tried to `Dim slide as Slide` also.

Is there some setting or parameter in PowerPoint I need to activate?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Since you are trying to run this from within Excel, try `Dim sld as Powerpoint.Slide` instead

Comment: @TimStack Thanks for getting back - 'user defined type not defined' is my error now. Seems VBA doesn't recognise Powerpoint.Slide as a valid type format.

Comment: Please give a [mcve], including the code in which you declare and give a value to `ActivePresentation` If this is Excel VBA, you don't have any direct access to PowerPoint objects.

Comment: Seems to me you're not creating a proper link between Excel and the Powerpoint presentation you are referring to. Is this the full code you are using?

Comment: @TimStack Indeed this is the full code. And I would agree with you. I am not a VBA programmer at all so am unsure how to make this link.

Comment: I'll get you an answer.. stand by

Comment: You'll need to get the PowerPoint application first with something like `Set objPPTApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")`

Comment: @TimStack Much appreciated.

Comment: @CLR I will try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim objPPTApp As Object
    Dim slide As Object

    Set objPPTApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

    For Each slide In objPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides

        Debug.Print "test"

    Next slide

End Sub
```

Comment: edit: no more errors but now nothing is happening. 'test' isn't being printed. This is progress though so thank you.

Comment: Code works fine for me. Foolishly had PowerPoint closed. The print statement still doesn't print for some reason, but that is fine, I just went with `msgBox("test")`. Thanks for the help all.

Comment: @CiaranDeCeol I would highly advise you not to use `ActivePresentation` but to properly refer to the specific presentation you intend to use. This would avoid errors when referring to the wrong presenation when another is accidentally activated. Generally using Activate or Select is bad practice.

Comment: Ciaran, to expand on Tim's comment - the answer above it purely to get your existing code working. As the code stands right now, it's definitely not best practice, as Tim points out. It really depends if you're looking to build something that you're running infrequently or something that you're looking to automate and that can deal with issues if they arise.

Comment: @CLR I absolutely agree with both of you. However, this is only for personal use to speed up my workflow so I'm not particularly worried about making it bullet proof.

Answer (score 1):

VBA has to know what application you are referring to, in order for it to loop through objects within that application.

**1. Open the VBA editor**

**2. In the top ribbon, click on `Tools` > `References`, and check the box for Microsoft PowerPoint X.0 Object Library**

Now you can identify the PowerPoint application and Presentation you want to refer to

```
Sub ppslides()

Dim pp As Object
Dim slide As Object
Dim PowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
Set PowerPoint GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")


'Loops through each open PP presentation and puts the presentation name in a messagebox
For Each pp In PowerPoint.Presentations
    MsgBox pp.Name
Next pp

'These variables can be populated and used to refer to a specific Presentation in the upcoming loop
ppname = "Example"
ppindex = 1


'Loops through all slides in the presentation and puts their names in a messagebox
'REF should be replaced with a name, index, or one of the above variables
For each slide In PowerPoint.Presentations(REF).Slides
    MsgBox slide.Name
Next slide

End Sub
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you for sharing this. I'm wondering now is it possible instead if using `slide.index` or `slide.name` to label my output, can one reference a custom array of names for example. `testArray = Array('test1','test2','test3')` Perhaps something along the lines of (pseudocode) MsgBox & i for i in testArray

Comment: Not too sure what it is you're trying to achieve.. Do you want all slides to be printed in a single MsgBox? Please clarify

Comment: That was just an example really. I'm actually exporting slides to .pdf and .jpg successfully. My query is really concerned about custom naming the output. I can use slide.name or slide.index. I am curious as to whether one can output files with custom naming based on storing names in an array. Again, this is for personal use only for printing a reoccurring report. Hardcoding names in an array is not worrysome for me as the slide names will always remain consistent and I am the only user.

Comment: You _can_ refer to specifically named slides- given that they do in fact exist, if that's what you're asking. My code simply returns the slides present in a particular presentation, so I do not understand why you want to return names stored in an array instead.. It's hard to follow what you are aiming for

Comment: That is probably the easiest way. Name slides specifically that is. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps read [this webpage](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.837.1.77/1/). You could, for instance, change the name of a particular slide with `PowerPoint.Presentations(1).Slides("Slide1").Name = "NewSlideName"`

Comment: That is a useful link, thank you for sharing. I appreciate the help.